# Is there a way in AEM to use dynamic data in `cq:htmlTag` or similar?

Tags: java, xml, adobe, aem

In order to avoid extraneous nested HTML elements in the DOM, we're attempting to attach some data to the injected `<div>` AEM adds (such as classnames, a unique UUID, etc.). For this question, the component in question will be a `Container`. It is supertyped to Adobe's `core/wcm/components/container/v1/container`. In the `container.html`, we further customize it by using our own Java Model:

```html
column.html
<sly
  data-sly-use.template="core/wcm/components/commons/v1/templates.html"
  data-sly-use.column="com.app.components.core.models.Column"
  data-sly-use.viewModel="${'authoring/column.js' @ dataModel=column, properties=properties}"
>
```

Some of the data used in our component is static and and some dynamic. In this case, the `component-name` is always the same; however, we also have a dynamic piece of data like `component-id` (which in our case, is a random UUID generated in the Java Implementation) or potentially in future, other data pieces such as the `class`.

From what I see, we are limited to declaring dynamic data in the `column.html`, and not in `cq:htmlTag`. For example, we add our dynamic data here in that file:

```html
column.html
<sly
  data-sly-use.template="core/wcm/components/commons/v1/templates.html"
  data-sly-use.column="com.app.components.core.models.Column"
  data-sly-use.viewModel="${'authoring/column.js' @ dataModel=column, properties=properties}"
>
  <!-- Dynamic Data comes from our Java implementation, such as `container.containerUUID` -->
  <meta
    data-sf-component-id="${container.containerUUID}"
    data-sf-version="${container.version}"
  />
</sly>
```

Any "static" data can safely be placed into cq:htmlTag and it will show up on the `<div>` which is added in the DOM, like so:

```xml
_cq_htmlTag/.content.xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jcr:root xmlns:cq="http://www.day.com/jcr/cq/1.0" 
  xmlns:jcr="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/1.0" 
  xmlns:nt="http://www.jcp.org/jcr/nt/1.0" 
  jcr:primaryType="nt:unstructured" 
  <!-- Static Data can be placed here. -->
  class="namespace-column-v1" 
  data-sf-component="Column" />
```

However, Dynamic data such as the ID must be nested as shown above in `column.html`, which is less than ideal in our case. Here's an example of what it looks like rendered:

```html
Rendered HTML
<!-- Static data is in parent div -->
<div
  class="namespace-column-v1 aem-GridColumn--default--none aem-GridColumn aem-GridColumn-- 
         offset--default--0 aem-GridColumn--default--1"
  data-sf-component="Column"
>
  <!-- Dynamic data must be nested, and not on the parent div. -->
  <meta data-sf-component-id="4b9eeb328439eded3045fe4cb8d8d24d" data-sf-version="v1">
  ...
</div>
```

Is it possible, whether by using `cq:htmlTag` or some other method, to ensure the topmost parent of our component also contains the Dynamic data we desire? Ideally, this solution is O(1) and doesn't require Javascript selectors or extra libraries we need to load, just to add a class to a `<div>`.

It seems like `cq:noDecoration` might be an option here, but that seems to complicate things further as I have heard this breaks the component being editable while being Authored.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: From what I understand, you want to add the dynamic data to the <div> element that wraps your whole component and is added by AEM. Have you tried using Sling's Output Rewriting Pipelines? I'm not sure what details are available in the context of the processor that you register, so it might be tricky to ensure if a particular div needs to be enriched. But maybe it's worth exploring.